# C++: Dynamically add structures to a container and retrieve them

Tags: c++, dynamic, containers

I need to be able to dynamically create and retrieve a structure based on what the string says and return it's corresponding float. I can place them in a set no problem but it's the dynamic creation that i just don't get.The structure I'm using is like this:

```
struct structure
{
    std::string string1 = "default";
    int integer1 = 0;
};
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: You can use [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) for your dynamic container needs, but Novelocrat has a better idea for you with [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/)

Comment: I think you're looking for a factory method pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're actually looking for `std::map<std::string, int>`? Cf http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a factory for object creation?

```
structure* createStructur(std::string name)
{
   if (name == "foo")
   {
       return new ...;
   }
   else if (name == "bar")
   {
       return new ...;
   }
   ...
}
```